# Kivy properties not automatically updating

Tags: kivy, python-3.5

I'm having trouble with binding properties across different rules using kivy language.

In particular, I'm trying to use a color picker to change the background color a few labels; I'm using a `ScreenManager` to handle two different `Screen`s, a main screen with just a `MyButton` instance (a subclass of `Label`, as can be seen in the code) and another screen with a `ColorPicker` and another `MyButton`.

Here's the code I'm working on:

`picker.py`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import BoundedNumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, \
    ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class MyScreen(Screen):
    my_picker = ObjectProperty(None)

class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    my_r = BoundedNumericProperty(1, min=0, max=1)
    my_g = BoundedNumericProperty(1, min=0, max=1)
    my_b = BoundedNumericProperty(1, min=0, max=1)
    my_a = BoundedNumericProperty(1, min=0, max=1)
    my_rgba = ReferenceListProperty(my_r, my_g, my_b, my_a)

class PickerApp(App):
    pass


def main():
    PickerApp().run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`picker.kv`

```
<MyButton@Label>:
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.my_rgba
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<PickerScreen@MyScreen>:
    my_picker: picker
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MyButton:
            my_rgba: picker.color
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: 1, .2
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'main'
        ColorPicker:
            id: picker

<MainScreen@MyScreen>:
    MyButton:
        my_rgba: root.my_picker.color if root.my_picker is not None else .5, .5, .5, 1
        text: "Picker"
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'picker'

ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
        name: 'main'
        my_picker: picker_screen.my_picker
    PickerScreen:
        name: 'picker'
        id: picker_screen
```

When I select a color on the `ColorPicker`, I want both buttons to change their background; but while the button in the `PickerScreen` changes on color selection, apparently the `my_rgba` of the button in the main screen isn't bound to `root.my_picker.color`, as I expected.

I thought the issue could be because of the if-then-else expression; but I tried initializing the `ObjectProperty` in `MyScreen` with a dummy value, removing the if-then-else expression, and the behaviour seems identical.

What am I doing wrong? I'm just starting with Kivy, but I thought that properties were automatically bound so that if `root.my_picker.color` changed, so should both the buttons `my_rgba` properties.

Comment: At the end you set `MainScren.picker = picker_screen.picker` didn't you want to set `MainScreen.my_picker = picker_screen.picker`?

Comment: @syntonym You're right; there were few other lines where I made the same mistake. I corrected them, but nothing changed; which seems to be expected, considering I think the issue is that `root.my_picker` is `None` at first, so `my_rgba` is bound to the constant `(.5, .5, .5, 1)` and is never updated

Comment: What happens if you set `ObjectProperty(rebind = True)` for the my_picker? [Relevant documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ObjectProperty)

Comment: @syntonym Perfect! It works exactly as I intended it to; I will gladly accept an answer, if you intend to write one. Otherwise I will answer myself in a few days. Thanks for the reference, I missed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is simply solved by changing the `my_picker` property in `MyScreen` in this way:

```
class MyScreen(Screen):
    my_picker = ObjectProperty(rebind=True)
```

As a consequence, when `root.my_picker` is set to something different from `None`, `my_rgba` in the `MyButton` instance in the main screen gets correctly rebound to the new value.